# Calculating variance of sensor readings from noise density

Tags: noise

I do not know much about signal processing and would appreciate if someone could confirm if my calculations are correct.

[image]

Here I have the Noise density of an accelerometer that has frequency 6400hz and will use full scale +-2g. I want to calculate the standard deviation of the sensor readings.

Here are my calculations:

\begin{align*}
\sigma &= 120\mu g \sqrt{6400} = 120 \times 9.8 \times 10^{-6} \times \sqrt{6400} = 0.09408 \ \text{ms}^{-2}
\end{align*}

Would these calculations be valid for calculating the standard deviation of the accelerometer readings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily- if the signal is not stationary (as is typically the case with accelerometer readings) the variance will not converge so you’ll get a different result depending on how many samples and sample duration. For this reason the Allan Variance is a more appropriate measure to determine an accelerometer’s quality with regards to noise performance.